# Why only near the top of wave is displayed ?I want to display its entire

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have trouble with the shape of superposed wave with threejs.
this wave made from plane material is displayed upper half of it ,but it is displayed correctly when turned upside down by mouse drugging.

```
// turn　the wave plane upside down by drugging 
console.clear()
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var W = window.innerWidth;
var H = window.innerHeight;
console.log("W "+W + "H"+ H)
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
//renderer.setClearColor(0xc482c4);
renderer.setSize(W, H);
renderer.shadowMap.enabled = true;
renderer.shadowMap.type = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; 

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(10, W / H, 1, 500);

var planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(200, 100, 200,100 );//planeの横、たて、横分割数、たて分割数
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
          color: 0x6699FF,
           side: THREE.BackSide
        });
//wireframe: true
var plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeometry, planeMaterial);
plane.castShadow = true;
plane.receiveShadow = true;
plane.rotation.x = -0.4 * Math.PI;
plane.position.set(0, 0, 10);
scene.add(plane);

var dlight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xC0C0C0,1 );
dlight.position.set(0,0,1);
dlight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(dlight);
var lights = [];
            lights[ 0 ] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
            lights[ 1 ] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
            lights[ 2 ] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );
      lights[ 3 ] = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 0 );

            lights[ 0 ].position.set( 0, 0, 20 );
            lights[ 1 ].position.set( 10, 20, 10 );
            lights[ 2 ].position.set( - 10, - 20,  -10 );
      lights[ 3 ].position.set( - 0, - 0,  -20 );

            scene.add( lights[ 0 ] );
            scene.add( lights[ 1 ] );
            scene.add( lights[ 2 ] );
      scene.add( lights[ 3 ] );

camera.position.set( 20, 0, 350 );
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( camera );
controls.enableZoom=true;
controls.update();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

(function drawFrame(ts){
  var centerLeft = new THREE.Vector2(-21,0);
  var centerRight = new THREE.Vector2(21,0);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
  var vLength = plane.geometry.vertices.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < vLength; i++) {
    var v = plane.geometry.vertices[i];
    var dist1 = new THREE.Vector2(v.x, v.y).sub(centerLeft);//中心からx,yまでの距離
    var dist2 = new THREE.Vector2(v.x, v.y).sub(centerRight);
    var size = 10.0;//wavelength
    var magnitude = 7;//amplitude
    v.z = 2*Math.sin(-2*Math.PI*dist1.length()/size + 2*Math.PI*(ts/2000)) +2*Math.sin(-2*Math.PI*dist2.length()/size+ 2*Math.PI*(ts/2000));
  }
  plane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}());
```

https://codepen.io/math_mountain_f/pen/Mdjvwx

I changed "plane.position".However, this plane didn't seem to move.

I am trying to correct camera position, it doesn't work for now.

I want to display the entire wave from top of view without drugging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change material side from THREE.BackSide to THREE.DoubleSide

```
var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
      color: 0x6699FF,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide
});
```

THREE.FrontSide would work as well if you are not going to look underneath, its the default so you can just delete that line.

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/constants/Materials

You can also rotate the plane by 180°